# I want to write a regex which replace duplicate string irrespective of case sensitive

Tags: java, regex

For example

```
String str="**Hello bye bye given given world world**"
```

should return

```
"**Hello bye given world**".
```

Comment: You don't need regex, just do `str = str.ReplaceDuplicateStringCaseInsensitive();` obviously you will need to implement that function, but I am sure you get the idea from the minimal information I have provided

Comment: 'world' and 'world**' are different by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by using space and and compare the string with previous string occurrences by storing the non duplicate values only in a list.

The code will be as follows.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test2 {
    private static final String SPACE = " ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replaceDuplicateString("**Hello Bye bye given given world world**"));
    }

    public static String replaceDuplicateString(String input) {
        List<String> addedList = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (String str: input.split(SPACE)) {
            if (!addedList.contains(str.toUpperCase())) {
                output.append(str);
                output.append(' ');
                addedList.add(str.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
        return output.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

This will print

```
Hello bye given world
```

How ever if you change the input to

```
**Hello bye bye given given world world**
```

the output will be

```
**Hello bye given world world**
```

Since, `world` is not a duplicate of `world**`.